# Javascript call doesn't work with phonegap-build

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cross-domain, phonegap

I'm going in circles for a week... I encounter a problem that many people encounter, but I still haven't found the solution. Everything works properly before compilation, but once compiled with Phonegap-Build and installed on my phone, my javascript doesn't work.

Here are my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#target").click(function(){

        $.post(

            'https://www.myurl.com/myfile.php',

            { login: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() },

            function(data){

                if(data.auth == "NOK"){

$("#resultat").html("<p>"+data.erreur+"</p>");                  

                }

                else{

localStorage.setItem("username", data.username);

localStorage.setItem("UniqID", data.UniqID);

document.location.href="accueil.html"

                } 

            },

            'json'

        );

    });

});
```

I have added at all my html pages :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';   connect-src * ; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I have added in my config.xml :

```
<access origin="*"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.3.3" />

<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />

<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

<allow-intent href="tel:*" />

<allow-intent href="sms:*" />

<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />

<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

I hope somebody could help me...

Thank you,

Deubow

Comment: If what doesn't work is the ajax call, the problem is probably a bad/untrusted certificate on the server

Comment: The certificate on the server is trusted by a AC (https://www.ecopellets.fr/)
If I replace the ajax call by a simple alert('hello'), it's working. The problem come from the ajax call.

Comment: It can be trusted but not correctly configured, like missing intermediate certificate, incorrect order of installation of the certificates, not using the default port or even an incorrect date/time on the device can cause https calls to fail.

Comment: Il don't thinks so. The certificate on the server seems to be good : https://www.ecopellets.fr

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ "seems". I'm just telling the common problems that can cause the ajax call to fail when the app is signed. You can try to add an error handler and see if it provides some more information

Comment: Thank for your help, I Will add an error handler to have more information. You are telling "when the app is signed"  : for now, the app isnt signed, its only for debug. Ajax call can fail if the app isnt signed ?

Comment: Then that changes things, if it doesn't even work with debug build the problem is not the certificate. I've tried to do a post to your applogin.php and seems to work fine

Comment: I've build it in PGB and it's working fine https://build.phonegap.com/apps/2986824/share

Comment: Yeah, your build works fine. Can You plezse share me your files to compare ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, my apk works fine now. I started from scratch my form and my ajax request and it's work with the cordova whitelist and CSP.